# @Published struct in SwiftUI does not published

Tags: swiftui

See my code below. My problem is if i change `accessToken` via `UserService.shared.currentStore.accessToken = xxx`, SwiftUI doesn't publish, and there's no update on `StoreBanner` at all.

```swift
//SceneDelegate
let contentView = ContentView()
    .environmentObject(UserService.shared)

//Define
class UserService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentStore = Store.defaultValues()

    static let shared = UserService()
}

struct Store: Codable, Hashable {
    var storeName: String = ""
    var accessToken: String = ""
}

//Use it
struct StoreBanner: View {
        var body: some View {
            Group {
                if UserService.shared.currentStore.accessToken.isNotEmpty {
                    ShopifyLinkedBanner()
                } else {
                    ShopifyLinkBanner()
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey! 

I think it’s because you are directly accessing the static instance property. You used an ‘@ObservableObject’ class with a ‘@published’ property which is right, but you never used an @ObservedObject for e.g to receive updates.

I’m on my phone but can give an code example when I’m back at my desk. essentially you need an ‘@ObservedObject property which is the store (or perhaps a store container which also publishes changes)

Comment: sorry just saw you pass the instance in environment. Maybe you can just use an environment object in your view and access that instead of the static instance ? @EnvironmentObject var store: UserService

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `UserService` inside `StoreBanner` without using a property wrapper to tell the view to respond to updates. Without the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper, the `View` doesn't have a mechanism to know that any of the `@Published` properties have been updated.

Try this:

```
struct StoreBanner: View {
  @ObservedObject private var userService = UserService.shared
  
  var body: some View {
            Group {
                if userService.currentStore.accessToken.isNotEmpty {
                    ShopifyLinkedBanner()
                } else {
                    ShopifyLinkBanner()
                }
            } 
   }
}
```

This should work assuming you set `accessToken` somewhere in your code on the same instance of `UserService`.

Comment: @LiangWang did this answer your question?